# Need latest timestamp on destination file if the source file is identical using ansible copy module

Tags: ansible, timestamp, copy

Is it possible to reflect the latest timestamp of the copy if the source and destination files are identical?

Timestamp before copy for destination and source:

destination:

```
[wluser@myhost7 ~]$ ls -ltr /tmp/out

-rw-r--r-- 1 wluser aces 0 Nov  4 23:56 /tmp/out
```

source:

```
[wluser@myhost7 ~]$ ls -ltr /home/wluser/out

-rw-r--r-- 1 wluser aces 0 Oct 12 05:06 /home/wluser/out
```

Ansible playbook:

```
[wluser@myhost7 ~]$ cat copytry.yml

- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - name: Copy a file to another location

      ansible.builtin.copy:

        src: /tmp/out

        dest: /home/wluser/out

        force: yes
```

Output:

```
[wluser@myhost7 ~]$ ansible-playbook copytry.yml

[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

 

 

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************

 

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************

Saturday 04 November 2023  23:57:47 -0500 (0:00:00.048)       0:00:00.048 *****

ok: [localhost]

 

TASK [Copy a file to another location] ****************************************************************************************

Saturday 04 November 2023  23:57:50 -0500 (0:00:02.884)       0:00:02.933 *****

ok: [localhost]

 

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************

localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

 

Saturday 04 November 2023  23:57:51 -0500 (0:00:00.554)       0:00:03.487 *****

===============================================================================

Gathering Facts -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 2.88s

Copy a file to another location ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.55s
```

Post copy timestamp:

```
[wluser@myhost7 ~]$ ls -ltr /home/wluser/out

-rw-r--r-- 1 wluser aces 0 Oct 12 05:06 out
```

I want the timestamp to be the latest i.e. `Nov 4` even if the src and dest files are identical.

I can fall back to using `raw` module with `cp -p src dest` to get the latest timestamp on the destination file but would lose on backup, file permissions and other attributes offered by the copy module.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`ansible.posix.synchronize`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) module (uses `rsync` behind the scene) that preserves the timestamp.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Copy a file to another location
      ansible.posix.synchronize:
        src: /tmp/out
        dest: /home/wluser/out
```